# How to handle nested for loops with complex data structures?

Tags: java, performance

Need to go through on a complex data structure and modify external variables from the algorithm.

I have tried to do it with stream but as far as I know it is not thread safe, can be race conditions...

Is there a better way than this below copied approach?

```
List<ObjectA> externalVariable = new ArrayList<>();
List<ObjectA> externalVariable2 = new ArrayList<>();

if (objectA != null) {
    externalVariable.add(objectA);

    for (ObjectB objectB : objectA) {
        if (objectB.getObjectC() != null) {
            for (ObjectD objectD : objectB.getObjectC()) {
                if (objectD.getObjectE() != null) {
                    for (ObjectE objectE : objectD.getObjectE()) {
                        if (objectE.getObjectF() != null) {
                            for (ObjectG objectG : objectE.getObjectF()) {
                                objectG.setSomething("BlaBla");

                                if (objectG.getOjectH() != null && objectG.getOjectH().getObjectI() != null) {
                                    for (ObjectI objectI : objectG.getOjectH().getObjectI()) {
                                        externalVariable2.add(objectI);
                                        ObjectJ objectJ = getRelevantOjectJ(objectA.getId(), objectI.getId());
                                        objectI.setObjectJ(objectJ);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Is there a better way than this below copied approach?*" - If the code works as intended and you want a review, the question might be better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Well, using streams is not less or more prone to race conditions as a simple `for` loop, as long as the stream is sequential.

Comment: how does this make sense? `for (ObjectB objectB : objectA)`

Comment: By the way, if an object is a sort of collection or stream (like `objectA` in your case), it should **never** be `null`.

Comment: @PatrickParker If `ObjectA impelements Iterable<ObjectB>` (which it must if the code works), this makes perfect sense (syntacticall, at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Race conditions occur when more than one thread execute concurrently statements that modify a shared state.
If your current code is thread safe, it will still be with stream while you don't use the parallel stream feature.
About your actual code : we can consider it is an arrow code, not easily to read and to maintain.

You have different approaches to reduce the global nesting but I don't encourage streams here because you don't collect into a result but you mutate external objects.   That is not a use case for stream.

You can remark in your current code that you iterate on many collections explicitly while the applied logic don't care about most of them.

Here, all that is performed only to get `ObjectG` instances, the remaining is not used then :

```
for (ObjectB objectB : objectA) {
    if (objectB.getObjectC() != null) {
        for (ObjectD objectD : objectB.getObjectC()) {
            if (objectD.getObjectE() != null) {
                for (ObjectE objectE : objectD.getObjectE()) {
                    if (objectE.getObjectF() != null) {
                        for (ObjectG objectG : objectE.getObjectF()) {
```

So encapsulate all of that into a method that collect `ObjectG` instances and return them.
Note that it could be written without stream but also with since for collecting them you don't need to modify a shared state.

Finally you method could be simplified as :

```
Collection<ObjectG> objectsG = collectG(objectA); // extracted method

for (ObjectG objectG : objectsG) {
    objectG.setSomething("BlaBla");

    if (objectG.getOjectH() != null && objectG.getOjectH().getObjectI() != null) {
        for (ObjectI objectI : objectG.getOjectH().getObjectI()) {
            externalVariable2.add(objectI);
            ObjectJ objectJ = getRelevantOjectJ(objectA.getId(), objectI.getId());
            objectI.setObjectJ(objectJ);
        }
    }
```